# Finding a substring and getting ride of everything after said substring in a variable in R

Tags: r, substr

I get how to find a substring, using `substr()` and `grep()`. My problem is getting rid of everything that comes after the substring. Here is an example of my dataset:

```
Williamsport, Pennsylvania !Williamsport, Pennsylvania 
El Cajon, California !El Cajon, California 
Gary, Indiana !Gary, Indiana
New York City                                  
Bowie, Maryland
```

I want to get rid of everything after " !".
Can I use an `ifelse()`, if so how?

Comment: Are you certain you will only ever have one exclamation mark?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sub()`.

```
sub(" !.*", "", x)
# [1] "Williamsport, Pennsylvania" "El Cajon, California"       "Gary, Indiana"
# [4] "New York City"              "Bowie, Maryland"
```

`.*` is a regular expression denoting any character, any number of times.  So this basically says "remove everything after and including `" !"`".

**Data:**

```
x <- c(
    "Williamsport, Pennsylvania !Williamsport, Pennsylvania", 
    "El Cajon, California !El Cajon, California", 
    "Gary, Indiana !Gary, Indiana", 
    "New York City", 
    "Bowie, Maryland"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
sub( "(.*)(\\ \\!.*)", "\\1", txtvec)
```

As suggested in comments this may not match the first instance of "!", but there would be a more specific pattern if that were a problem.